# Laravel time table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am making a time table in Laravel where user can select one field at say 10:00, and reserve equipment until say 12:00.

I have trouble displaying the range from when to when the equipment is reserved

```
@while($scheduler_start_time < $scheduler_end_time)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$scheduler_start_time->format('H:i:s')}}</td>
        @foreach($equipment as $instrument)
            <td>
                <a href="#">

                    @if($instrument->reservations->where('reserved_from','=', $scheduler_start_time)
                    ->where('reserved_to','<=', $scheduler_end_time)->first() != null)

                        HERE

                    @else
                        &nbsp;
                    @endif
                </a>
            </td>
        @endforeach
        <?php $scheduler_start_time->addMinutes(30) ?>
    </tr>
@endwhile
```

One instrument can have many reservations:

[image]

And this is what I get when getting reservation where `reserved_from` equals time. If I use `>=` I am fetching both records. I need a way to see that for example: Instrument3 is reserved from 6:30 up to 7:30, and then from 9:30 to 10:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your problem, I think you just need to add an upper limit on the 'reserved_from'. Would this work?

```
@if($instrument->reservations->where('reserved_from','>=', $scheduler_start_time)->where('reserved_from', '<', $scheduler_end_time)->where('reserved_to','<=', $scheduler_end_time)->first() != null)
```

UPDATE: Solved by OP

```
@if($instrument->reservations ->where('reserved_from','<=', $scheduler_start_time) ->where('reserved_to','>=', $scheduler_start_time)->first() != null
```

Comment: Unfortunately no...`$scheduler_start_time` starts at 6:00 and `$scheduler_end_time` is fixed on 20:00, so this selects some rows in between which shouldn't be selected

Comment: Ah, ok. So, maybe we need to add the upper limit to the reserved_to then? `->where('reserved_from', '<=', $scheduler_start_time)->where('reserved_to', '>=', $scheduler_start_time)->where('reserved_to','<=', $scheduler_end_time)`

Comment: I've solved it yesterday, you were on the right track, you can update it `@if($instrument->reservations
                                        ->where('reserved_from','<=', $scheduler_start_time)
                                        ->where('reserved_to','>=', $scheduler_start_time)->first() != null)`

Comment: Good! I do need to add that running this many queries on a single page will put a huge strain on your database. You can look into [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and caching your results.

Comment: Well, I did eager load `equipment` with `reservations` and `reservations.user`, so I suppose it will work ok